# Access a csv file mounted from a Windows server into a directory on the same Linux server as SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, cifs

I have SQL Server running on a linux server. The linux server is running cifs and has mounted a share from a Windows server containing a csv file.

I an trying to run a script that will bulk-insert the contents of the csv into a table on the SQL Server.

```
BULK INSERT autobilling..whse_ABC
FROM '//192.168.0.211/mnt/ABC/ABC.csv'
WITH
(
  FORMAT='csv',
  FIRSTROW=2
)
```

File permissions are -r-xr-xr-x

The error message I get from SSMS is:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot bulk load. The file "//192.168.0.211/mnt/ABC/ABC.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

Appreciate any help I can get...

Comment: Have you tried accessing the local mountpoint instead of the share path? What account is the SQL Server service executing under (usually it's `mssql`)? Does the service user (e.g.: `mssql`) have permissions to the local mountpoint?

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track.  I ended up taking out the server IP from the script, and the error changed to ```Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"```.  I then added the field terminator and row terminator instructions and the import worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you got me on the right track. I ended up taking out the server IP from the script, and the error changed to Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)". I then added the field terminator and row terminator instructions and the import worked.